# iphone email posting form data

Tags: iphone, forms, email, post

I have an html form within an email (I know this isn't the best practice).  I am able to have the form transmit data via POST in gmail, however, in iphone mail it the POST array is empty.  Does anyone have any insight into this, could it possibly be a security setting, etc?  Thanks!

Comment: it's just a regular html form sent inside an html email body:<form name='asdf' action='http://asdf.com' method='post' target='_blank'><input type='text' name='testValue'/><input type='submit' value='submit'></form>

Answer (score 1):

A lot of email clients block POST requests from being sent from within an email. Allowing POST requests is dangerous in many ways. It can make phishing and XSS emails even more malicious. If you want your email to function properly in every email client (which is hard as it is), you should leave out POST requests. If possible, do a GET instead by appending a query string to a URL. That would have 100% support, so hopefully you can accomplish what you want to do like that.